# Looping through Range and Hiding Columns VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, hide, range

I am super ill today and very new at VBA - not a recipe for success. I'm trying to loop through each cell in a (horizontal) range, and if the text inside the cell is FALSE then i want to hide that column. This is what I've got so far:

```
Dim rRange As Range
Dim rCell As Range
rRange = Worksheets("Data").Range("W7:AH7").Cells

For Each rCell In rRange
        If rCell.Value = "FALSE" Then rCell.Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Next rCell
End Sub
```

I get error "object variable or with block variable not set". Please could somebody point out where i'm going wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
set rRange = Worksheets("Data").Range("W7:AH7").Cells
```

and

```
If Ucase(rCell.Value) = "FALSE" Then rCell.Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
```

Objects variables need set to create a instance, and "FALSE" <> "false", use Ucase to ignore diferences.

[]´s

Comment: Thanks very much! I didn't realise you had to put in Set like that... as for the upper/lowercase that is not a problem since the cell literally contains "FALSE". However, this all seems to run fine now but the Columns are not hidden at the end. I thought EntireColumn.Hidden = True would hide them instantly? Thanks again